# How to combine two `hello.init` into one?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, hello.js

I am trying to use [hello.js init API](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#helloinit) to sign in Microsoft Graph later. The code below is how I am doing now and it works.

<kbd>[repo](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/microsoft-graph-angular/blob/master/src/app/auth/services/auth.service.ts#L14-L29)</kbd>

However, is there a way to combine these two `hello.init` into one? Thanks

```
hello.init({
  msft: {
    oauth: {
      version: 2,
      auth: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
    },
    scope_delim: ' ',
    form: false
  }
});

hello.init({
  msft: myAppId
}, {
  redirect_uri: window.location.href
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this suggestion? https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/issues/470

Comment: Hmm, just tried, that way does not provide the app ID, and it also returns the error `The provided network was not recognized` when use `aad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the creator of hello.js Andrew Dodson on [GitHub](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/issues/512).

> `hello.init ({msft:appid})` is short for `hello.init ({msft:{id:appid}})`
>   so you just need to define an id prop on your definition and it'll all
>   work. Fyi this is undocumented and may change in the future.

So in my case, the solution is

```
  hello.init({
      msft: {
        id: myAppId,
        oauth: {
          version: 2,
          auth: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
        },
        scope_delim: ' ',
        form: false
      },
    },
    { redirect_uri: window.location.href }
  );
```